# Is there any way to ignore or omit substitution of hash values in a regex in perl?

Tags: regex, perl

So I have a regex in perl which goes like,

```
my $texttosub = "log10(blackcat)";
#the value of "blackcat" can be found in a hash called "%cats"
if ( $texttosub =~ s|([a-zA-Z][A-Za-z_0-9]+)|$cats{$1}|i ){          
  print ("\n", " The value of cat = ", eval ($texttosub) );
  ..do something..
}
sub log10{....}
```

My question is, How do I ignore "log10" and only match "blackcat" for substitution? So that I can evaluate that "$texttosub" line and print of the log10 value of that "blackcat".

Comment: there's probably a better way to do what you need... for the regex question, try `$texttosub =~ s/log10(*SKIP)(*F)|[a-zA-Z]\w+/$cats{$1}/` (see https://www.rexegg.com/backtracking-control-verbs.html#skipfail)

Comment: If the argument you want to substitute for is always in parenthesis you could try:  `s|(?<=\()([a-zA-Z][A-Za-z_0-9]+)(?=\))|$cats{$1}|i`. This will ignore `log10` since it is not inside a pair of parenthesis

Comment: @HåkonHægland No. What I am looking for is, say blackcat=>5, whitecat=>10,orangecat=>20, then, $texttosub = "log10(blackcat)*whitecat*(log10(orangecat))" ===>must become  log10(5)*10*(log10(20)) irrespective of paranthesis.

Comment: So you want to differentiate between words that are in the hash `%cat` and those that are not (like `log10`)? If the word is in the hash `%cat`, then we do the substitution, else we leave it alone?

Comment: [Crossposted to PerlMonks](https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=1212142) (with answers there).

Answer (score 2):

There are two main approaches:

1. Match every word. If it appears in the hash, substitute the value, otherwise leave it alone (i.e. replace it by itself):

   ```
   $texttosub =~ s{\b([a-zA-Z]\w*)\b}{ $cats{$1} // $1 }eg;
   ```
2. Construct a regex from your hash keys and only match those words:

   ```
   use Data::Munge qw(list2re);
   my $regex = list2re keys %cats;
   $texttosub =~ s/\b($regex)\b/$cats{$1}/g;
   ```

Comment: Thanks. Which approach is better in the long run.

Comment: @RaveenKumar Neither. Using `eval` on user input is generally a bad idea.

Comment: Then how do you evaluate multiple expressions. For Example, lets say multiple expressions are stored in an array or hash. @melpomene

Comment: @RaveenKumar If they're expressions in my program, I'd store them as subroutines. If they're user input, I'd write a parser. Or at least a validator.

Comment: Congratulations on 40k !  :))